# Unable to access current value of Global Variable in Java

Tags: java, android, json

Below is my code, lat_val and long_val is not getting updated with received value from JSON response in `btnShowLoc()`, it is referencing to the default value which is 0,0. I want the global variable to keep updating when ever referenced and updated with JSON response.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public static String lat_val = "0";
    public static String long_val = "0";

    public String readJSONFeed(String urlStr) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("SisApiKey", "4572c3c9-73cb-4958-9649-26c1e8df27e8");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("SisSmartKey", "d1aebd25-774c-4e8a-b3a5-ee5a603cc603");

            InputStream ins = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            urlConnection.connect();
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));

                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                ins.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask
            <String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            return readJSONFeed(url[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                //JSONObject flags = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("flag"));
                JSONObject locationItems = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("response"));
                //Log.v("Location Details :", locationItems.toString());
                String []dev_loc = locationItems.toString().split("[\\s*,\\s*]");
                MainActivity.lat_val = dev_loc[0]; //"12.9934136";
                MainActivity.long_val = dev_loc[1]; //"80.2464206";

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ReadJSONFeedTask", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public void btnGetDevLoc(View view) {

        String sp_val = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());

        new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute(
                "http://15.153.133.160:21743/sis/sie/api/v1/applications/bb9f05fb-a796-4b75-9db7-c999360ad185/virtualobjects/d77d3905-aa77-41b9-9034-b0052bfde405?secondString=HWE_ASSET_ANDROID"); // + sp_val);
    }


    public void btnShowLoc(View view) {

        //lat_val = "12.9934136";
        //long_val = "80.2464206";

        Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString("latitude", MainActivity.lat_val);
        bundle.putString("longitude", MainActivity.long_val);
        in.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(in);
    }
```

Comment: are you calling btnGetDevLoc(View view) for getting json response?Does Api return latitude and longitude?

Comment: @NiravShah , yes I am calling btnGetDevLoc for getting json response and same response will contain latitude n longitude. Which I am using to send to Google Maps.

Sample JSON response :

{"flag":true,"response":"[12.9934136,80.2464206]","__metadata__":{"InteractionContextID":"de0aca1d-fa66-4536-aad9-7a22164abc73","transactionId":"VO_AS_825c6a1d-0d25-4758-950f-d0064ac2e5e5"}}

Comment: When you call btnGetDevLoc(View view) ? before btnShowLoc() or After that?

Comment: First btnGetDevLoc() is called then btnShowLoc()

Comment: remove static from variable or if you have inner class than you need to declare static asynch class to access static variable..

Comment: Without static key word also issue was same. After which i used static.
Can you explain what you mean by static asynch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158498/discussion-between-nirav-shah-and-srijan-chaudhary).

Answer (score 1):

With the few information you have shared, and given that

> `btnGetDevLoc()` and `btnShowLoc()`are the functions executed when clicked on buttons in the application defined in activity_main.xml

and that

> First `btnGetDevLoc()` is called then `btnShowLoc()`

the first thing that pops out in my mind is that the `AsyncTask` has not yet finished updating the `String` values, when you call `btnShowLoc()`.

So, if `btnGetDevLoc()` and `btnShowLoc()` are called sequentially, like

```
... onClick() {
   btnGetDevLoc();
   btnShowLoc();
}
```

then it's most likely due to what I said above. Remember that `AsyncTask` runs asynchronously (as the name says...).

---

You can test this really small program.

```
public static double var1 = 0.0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        var1 = 1.0;
    }).start();

    System.out.println(var1);
}
```

It will almost **always** print `0.0`, because the value of `var1` is not updated yet when the main thread prints it.

---

What you should do is place your `btnShowLoc()` call at the end of `onPostExecute(String)`. This guarantees that your method is called **only** after you have updated the new values.

Comment: as per my knowledge, doInBackGround() method is executed asynchronously. Here, m calling the readJSONFeed() method to get information. When the result is obtained, it is returned to the onPostExecute() method.

Comment: @SrijanChaudhary yes tha's true, but there is no guarantee that `onPostExecute()` is executed before `btnShowLoc()`

Comment: btnShowLoc() is executed only after the button is clicked in the app. I tried clicking the button even after 15min, but still value didn't get updated.

Comment: @SrijanChaudhary ok so this differs from the details you provided. You must provide more information. check the log, print the values in `onPostExecute()`. Make sure that that they are set. Update your answer then I'll come back.

Answer (score -1):

I can't Understand, when the btnGetDevLoc() and btnShowLoc() called? Can you post your whole MainActivity?

Edit :

It's seems like you call btnShowLoc() before your AsyncTask finish its proccess.
You can change your code this way to make sure your btnShowLoc() called after your AsyncTask :

```
public class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask
        <String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        return readJSONFeed(url[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            //JSONObject flags = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("flag"));
            JSONObject locationItems = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("response"));
            //Log.v("Location Details :", locationItems.toString());
            String []dev_loc = locationItems.toString().split("[\\s*,\\s*]");
            MainActivity.lat_val = dev_loc[0]; //"12.9934136";
            MainActivity.long_val = dev_loc[1]; //"80.2464206";

            btnShowLoc(dev_loc[0], dev_loc[1]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ReadJSONFeedTask", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}

public void btnShowLoc(String latitude, String longitude) {

    //lat_val = "12.9934136";
    //long_val = "80.2464206";

    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("latitude", latitude);
    bundle.putString("longitude", longitude);
    in.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

Comment: Please ask in comment if you want more details about question.

Comment: I cant, i have no reputation yet, 
I will edit my post and post my answer later

Comment: Ardy Maulana btnGetDevLoc() and btnShowLoc() are the functions executed when clicked on buttons in the application defined in activity_main.xml.